# CSS- link to an icon visible on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have an icon that I display on top, right of a div on hovering over the div. My code is like this:

```
<div class='edit_hover_class'>
   <!-- some code -->
</div>
```

And the corresponding css file contains:

```
.edit_hover_class:hover {
  background: url("trash.gif") no-repeat scroll right top;
}
```

I want to attach a link to the edit icon, is it possible with plain css? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with plain CSS.  What's wrong with putting the link in the HTML?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the link anyway?

Comment: To reduce clutter. Just like this comment shows 'this is a great comment' or 'flag this comment...' only on hover.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could hide a link until hover like so:

```
<div class='edit_hover_class'>
   <a href='#'><img src='icons/trash.gif' /></a>
</div>

.edit_hover_class a{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.edit_hover_class:hover a {
 visibility:visible;
}
```

See jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Auzm5/

Or if you only want the icon to link, use CSS `visibility`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Auzm5/1/

Comment: wont this also hide the image?

Comment: @CecilTheodore It will hide the icon until hover over the div yes. I believe this is what the OP requires.

Comment: Well how can anyone see the trash can unless they hover over it? another option would be to create 2 images, both positioned absolutely over the top of the other. The one on top is contained within a link and is Display:none. On hover over the lower image, The link then Display:block and is clickable.

Comment: OP doesn't want the trash can to appear until div is hovered over. I don't believe anything needs to be changed with this script.

Comment: Its not just the trash icon they hover on, they hover over the entire div. It has a lot more code.

Answer (score -3):

I havent tested this but its worth a try:

**HTML**

```
<div class='edit_hover_class'>
   <a href='#'><img src='icons/trash.gif' /></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.edit_hover_class a {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

.edit_hover_class a:hover {
   pointer-events: auto;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This code seems pointless. You won't see the cursor type or pointer-events until hover anyway.